# Services Menu item cocoa

Tags: cocoa, xamarin

[image: Menu Item]

When I run my application, I don't see a sub menu when I click on Services.
I want my app to look like the image attached, but I do not get a sub menu when I click on the triangle next to Services.

Is there an action in first responder that "Services" need to be connected to ?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new Cocoa app via the project template (`New project / Mac / App / Cocoa App`) the `Main.storyboard` will contain a default menu that includes an `App Menu` with the basic items, include `Services`:

[image]

If you have deleted those default menu items, you can add them back via Xcode's Interface Builder. Xamarin has a complete walk-thru @

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/user-interface/working-with-menus/#The_Default_Application_Menu_Bar

**Note:** If you care just trying to get the "System Preferences" to show up under your "Services" `menuItem` you can tag the submenu as `systemMenu="services"`

```
<menuItem title="Services" id="NMo-om-nkz">
    <modifierMask key="keyEquivalentModifierMask"/>
    <menu key="submenu" title="Services" systemMenu="services" id="hz9-B4-Xy5"/>
</menuItem>
```